# How to bold <optgroup> label for mac under Chrome Version 62.0.3202.94?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple select box with a `<optgroup>` in my application. I have already applied font-weight on `<optgroup>` but is not affect anything. I use chrome browser on MAC.

Thanks in advance.

```
<select>
   <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
     <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
     <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 </optgroup>
  ----
  ----
  ----
</select>
```

Comment: These links already shown, but I have not been working. Please tell me another way of fixing this problem?

Comment: @weBer It is a straight up copy/paste...

Comment: @snehapatel which version of chrome are you using.?

Comment: @Rloqvist copy just only example for your reference, but if you have known how to fix this problem. Please tell me.

Comment: @weBer Chrome Version 62.0.3202.94

Comment: @snehapatel, okay but if you actually read the other question you will find that the `select` element isn't really applicable to styling

Comment: @snehapatel we can only apply style to `<select>` with the help of plugins eg: https://select2.org/

Comment: @Rloqvist It's not important which text to copy or not. So Please not testing for my language.

Comment: @weBer these issues is not fixed through css or javascript.

Comment: @snehapatel we can't fix this using **CSS**, most common solution is to use it with a plugin - I prefer jQuery plugin(it's up to you)[name of the plugin I have given above]

Comment: @weBer  I can't use select2 plugin because i have already use jquery. Ex: https://github.com/codrops/TextInputEffects/blob/master/index.html

Comment: @snehapatel no issue on that you can use multiple jQuery plugins on website